# От куда берется Cursor="Hand" и другие?

Tags: wpf, .net-5

В последнее время в XAML разметке приложения на кнопках и текстовых полях стали автоматически появляться св-во Cursor (Hand для кнопок, IBeam для текстовых полей). Никаких расширений для написания кода не установлено.
[image: Пример из кода]
.NET 5.0 WPF

Comment: Оно там всегда было

Comment: @こきん Не согласен, не было. Код пишу руками, визуальным конструктором не пользуюсь, только чтобы посмотреть, что выходит

Comment: Это просто не показывало его раньше... Он был всегда https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.cursor?view=net-5.0#-------------

Comment: Нет, я понимаю, коненчо, что свойство там было всегда, но зачем его автоматически стало прописывать в разметку?

Comment: В каком смысле автоматически? При наборе текста подсказки?

Comment: Нет, вообще автоматически, собираешь проект и хоп, появилось Cursor="Hand", из пустоты просто